# How to add text which contains enters and special characters in the begin of a file

Tags: bash, sed

I want to add the following text in the beginning of a file (I want to keep the enters):

```
try {
    require('/opt/dynatrace-oneagent-6.5/agent/bin/any/onenodeloader.js')({server: 'http://test:8042', agentName: 'test'});
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.toString());
}
```

I know there are some questions abouts it. But I'm just not able to let it work. This is one of the things I tried.  what I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -i '1itry {
    require('/opt/dynatrace-oneagent-6.5/agent/bin/any/onenodeloader.js')({server: 'http://test:8042', agentName: 'test'});
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.toString());
}' output.json
```

but than I got: `sed: -e expression #1, char 127: unexpected`}'`

Comment: robust way would be to save the text in a file and use the `r` command

Comment: I think I found a Problem you start the sed with `'` so the string just goes to the next `'` so use `"` after require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert multiline string, try to add a trailing `\` except for the last one:

```
sed -i '1i \
try { \
    require('/opt/dynatrace-oneagent-6.5/agent/bin/any/onenodeloader.js')({server: 'http://test:8042', agentName: 'test'}); \
} catch (err) { \
    console.error(err.toString()); \
}
' output.json
```

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid `sed` due to presence of newlines all the special meta characters in your text.

You can just do it in shell like this with `cat`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set your multiline variable
read -rd '' text<<'EOF'
try {
    require('/opt/dynatrace-oneagent-6.5/agent/bin/any/onenodeloader.js')({server: 'http://test:8042', agentName: 'test'});
} catch (err) {
    console.error(err.toString());
}
EOF

# use echo + cat to print variable before file content and redirect
echo "$text" | cat - output.json > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp output.json
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and bash);

```
cat <<\! | sed -i '1ecat' file
try {
     require('/opt/dynatrace-oneagent-6.5/agent/bin/any/onenodeloader.js')({server: 'http://test:8042', agentName: 'test'});
}
catch (err) {
      console.error(err.toString());
}
!
```

Put the required lines in a here-document and use the evaluate command to cat it into start of the file

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
sed -i '1 i\try { require('/opt/dynatrace-oneagent-6.5/agent/bin/any/onenodeloader.js')({server: 'http://test:8042', agentName: 'test'});} catch (err) { console.error(err.toString());}'
```

I guess the i\ was missing.

Comment: I tried it but seems not to work in my case. I think it's important to know I want to keep my enters (not all on one line)

Comment: Ok, for me it works.I guess than it has something to do with operating system and version.